# How to prevent people take Application ID and Client ID from Parse core data request?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I use Parse to send a request, get data from Core Data of Parse service. But when I use Charles to catch the request, I see that it show the Application ID and Client ID in request header. That mean people can use these to destroy my data. How can I prevent people get Application ID and Client ID from Parse request?

Init parse:

```
[Parse enableLocalDatastore];

[Parse setApplicationId:@"71sGtWWba1AgjP8PpprdMFYOlxSHjVzScYRWuaaa"
              clientKey:@"ivO7FUz3botgxpi0ewJiDHjVQmFocTOQGBlINbbb"];
```

Get data:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Player"];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * _Nullable obj, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"%@; error %@", obj, error);
}];
```

Request header from Charles:

```
POST /1/classes/Player HTTP/1.1
Host: api.parse.com
X-Parse-Client-Version: i1.12.0
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
X-Parse-Application-Id: 71sGtWWba1AgjP8PpprdMFYOlxSHjVzScYRWuaaa
X-Parse-Client-Key: ivO7FUz3botgxpi0ewJiDHjVQmFocTOQGBlINbbb
X-Parse-Installation-Id: 2ad968fd-a5bd-46d5-898a-39a0168bcccc
Accept-Language: vi-vn
X-Parse-OS-Version: 9.2.1 (13D15)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 29
User-Agent: ParsePusher/1 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.0.0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Parse-App-Build-Version: 1
X-Parse-App-Display-Version: 1.0

{"limit":"1","_method":"GET"}
```

It also happen when I use my own Parse server

Comment: Parse-Application-ID and Parse-client-Key are PUBLIC key. To protect your data you must use ACL and CLP rules from your Parse DataBase

Comment: @toofoo Can you give me some document about how to use "ACL and CPL" on Parse SDK iOS? I'm using Parse SDK iOS newest version

Comment: From client side you can put ACL by following this doc : [link](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-security-for-other-objects ) For CPL I recommend you to define them derectly from the Parse Admin Console. But take notice that Parse service will shut down next year

Comment: @toofoo I found that ACL is the limitation of a data accesss, could be accessed by only current user or all users. But what I need is limit other developers access my data. How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

To access your data, people (users or developers) need one of the key defined in the  Parse admin console, in the "Settings" tab.
Of course the Master Key have all access and must be kept SECRET.
 
The client Key is deployed on each of your application device, so even if you could encrypt this key by yourself, you must consider it as public key.
To restrict access (read/write) to people having this key you should use both CPL and ACL
[ACL](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#security-object-level-access-control) (Object-Level Access Control) can be customize for each element of each Classes (like each row in a table)
[CPL](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#security-class-level-permissions) (Class Level Permission) define some global access rules for each Classes (a kind of "table" access). You can define CPL in the admin console by clicking on the "security" button" (in the core/Data tab).
By default a public access is defined, so people having you client key and application ID could access your data. You can define some rules to limit for i.e. the access to only authenticated user or event create a kind of "admin" Role to some data access. You can define different rules for read and write access.
The only weakness I see, is that if a data has a public access (read/write), it can be read (or even written) by other "developers" having the client key.

Comment: don't forget that Parse will end his service next year !!

Comment: Parse.com will end in next year. So I don't use it. I use open source Parse server deploy on Heroku. ACL, CPL cannot prevent other developers create new class without restriction permission and add data to these new class.

Comment: in the Parse admin console on the general setting you had an option to Allow client class creation. But I don't know how to do with the open source Parse Server